# Do I have to break a full property set to pay if I owe money in monopoly deal?

Tags: monopoly-deal

I owe 5 million due to rent and I have only a full property set.

Do I have to break the full set to pay or do I keep the property set and pay nothing?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR - Yes you will have to break a full set.

Looking at the rules [here](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=instructionbook#top) regarding payment of rent it says

> If you have no cards in front of you to pay with, you don't pay at
>   all.

So, if you are able to pay the rent you must do.  As you have a full set in front of you, you have cards.  Therefore you must pay.

There is nothing in the rules that says once you have a set it is 'safe' somehow and can not be broken.

Comment: Absolutely correct, the confusion might stem from the fact that complete sets are "safe" from cards like Sly Deal and Forced Deal. Other players can't make you break a set with these cards, but they can force you to do it yourself if you have no other way of paying a debt.